# Assigning variables to the Get HTTP request in R

Tags: r, http, rcurl

Is there any way to assign variable to a **http GET request** form using **rcurl**?

**eg:**

```
getURL("https://testme.com/www//LoginService/login?login=xyz&password=<variable>")
```

I need to pass the value of password as a variable.

Regards ...

Comment: Just for future contributions: 1. make sure you include desired output (even if in pseudo code or whatnot) to make your intent clear as Brita filtered water. 2. always check your questions against: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for ideal formatting.

Answer (score 3):

What about using `paste0`?

```
library("RCurl")
mypw <- "may1989"
basereq <- "https://testme.com/www//LoginService/login?login=xyz&password="
fullreq <- paste0( basereq, mypw, "/" )
```

So the full request looks like:

```
fullreq
## [1] "https://testme.com/www//LoginService/login?login=xyz&password=may1989/"
```

which you can curl in:

```
getURL(fullreq)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try httr:

```
library(httr)

GET("https://testme.com/www/LoginService/login", 
  query = list(login = "xyz", password = variable)
)
```

httr will automatically escape `variable` as needed.