# How to interpolate string into RCurl's URL?

Tags: r, url, rcurl

I want to insert a string into an url

```
library(RCurl)
myfile <- getURL('http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/',INSERT_STRING_HERE,'/E0.csv')
```

Is there a way to insert string into an url? Thank you

Comment: Just `paste()` it in, like any other string concatenation in R.

Comment: I followed this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902013/assigning-variables-to-the-get-http-request-in-r   and it works, thanks